# PDO extend for a crud querys and Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a query class for a CRUD and want extend the connection from other class, but i get a error : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object !?
What i miss ? Or is it just stupito to extend it ?

Here my MYsql_connection what extend to Querys class. Both are different php files.

```
class Mysql_connection extends Querys
{

    protected $dbh = null;

        function __construct()
        {
                try
                {
                    $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host; dbname=db','user','pass', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=> 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    $this->dbh = null; 
                    print('Error on connection'.$e->getMessage());
                    die();
                }
        }
}
```

And here is a Query class

```
class Querys{

    function getData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM db";

        $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $result = execute();

        $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    return = $data;
    }

}
```

Comment: how about replacing $dbh->prepare with $this->dbh... doh =]

Comment: @user3500781 Too change `$result = execute();` to `$result->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
$this->dbh->prepare($sql);
```

instead of

```
$dbh->prepare($sql);
```

You will also need to replace

```
return = $data;
```

with

```
return $data;
```

Remember that [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) is a statement, not a [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)!

Furthermore, `Mysql_connection extends Querys` is incorrect use of [inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php). `A extends B` means that `A` is a subtype of `B`.

Using a real-world example, `Dog` could be a subtype of `Animal`. Because a dog is an animal, right? So `Dog extends Animal` would be correct.

However, a `Connection` is not a `Query`!

I strongly recommend you to read a bit about inheritance and object oriented programming. ;)